# Prioridad a archivos y no a carpetas .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

Oculte las extensiones PHP con .htaccess, tengo por ejemplo el siguiente archivo: "avisos.php" que al acceder en el navegador escribo: dominio.com/avisos, el problema es que tengo una carpeta nombrada con el mismo nombre: "avisos" y esto me da un error 403 Forbidden, me seria mucho problema renombrar la carpeta o archivo, puedo solucionar esto con .htaccess?﻿

Answer (score 0):

Esta configuración te puede servir

```
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

La extrage de aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086473/htaccess-remove-file-extension-and-allow-folder-of-same-name